# How to filter objects depending on the properties of children in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What I have a list of persons each person has a list of Recoding (class) as a property.
There are several objects in the list.
If one of these objects is not empty, I want to add the person to a new list.

I did it with foreach-loops, but how does it work in LINQ?

```
List<Individual> Persons = new List<Person>();

foreach (Person person in Persons)
{
    foreach (Recording recording in person.Recordings)
    {
        if (recording.myProperty != "")
        {
            if (!Foo.Contains(person))
            {
                Foo.Add(person);
            }
        }
    }
}

Persons = Foo;
```

Comment: check Linq's  `.Any()` extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that *Linq* should be something like this:

```
List<Individual> Foo = Persons
  .Where(person => person.Recordings
     .Any(recording => (recording.myProperty != "")))
// .Distinct() // <- Uncomment if Persons contains duplicates
  .ToList();
```

We scan all `Persons` and get all items which have at least one `recording` with not empty `myProperty` value.